# SurfaceView displays blank screen on some Android 12 devices after updating targetSDK to 31

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-mediacodec, decoder, android-12

After updating the device to Android 12 some devices in Samsung A series display blank/ black SurfaceView where the frames are drawn.
The frames are drawn by the application using Mediacodec decoder H264 format

```
MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 1280, 720);
decoder.configure(mediaFormat, mSurfaceHolder.getSurface(), null, 0);
```

The logs are not available as it is on an end user device.
The old app with targetSDK 30 works on same device without any issues. The issue occurs after changing targetSDK to 31.

Tried changing the SurfaceView dimentions to even numbers as suggested for some devices but the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question as I was able to solve it. Making the SurfaceView dimensions to be multiple of 16 did the job.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34488156)